# Magento 2 module to extend Customer issue

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I'm trying to create a Magento 2 module to extend the default `Customer::loadByEmail()` class and method with some additional logic.

As my module contains a few different classes/files, I've created a public gist containing the code, rather than pollute this post with heaps of code.

Full code: https://gist.github.com/JasonMortonNZ/90ada76ad5511a37d2c6

Also for reference all code is located in the folder `project-root/app/code/Jason/OCUsers`.

What's working:

- The module is being recognised my Magento when I run the `magento module:status` command from the command line.
- I can successfully enable and disable the module, although the migrations (schema upgrades) do not seem to run.

What's **NOT** working:

- The schema updates on install and upgrade do not seem to work. No database schema updates persist or take effect.
- It would appear the DI isn't correct as the new `Customer` class and `loadByEmail` method I created are not being hit.

Any help or suggestions on why these couple of issue are occurring would be much appreciated :)

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jason_OCUser" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface" type="Jason\OCUser\Model\Customer" />
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Model\ActionValidator\RemoveAction">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="protectedModels" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer" xsi:type="string">Jason\OCUser\Model\Customer</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Customer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Jason\OCUser\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as MCustomer;

class Customer extends MCustomer
{
    /**
     * Load customer by email
     *
     * @param   string $customerEmail
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function loadByEmail($customerEmail)
    {
        die('Not reaching this :( ');
    }
}
```

**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Jason\OCUser\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Add salt column and oc user status
         */
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            'customer_entity',
            'oc_salt',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'length' => 9,
                'comment' => ''
            ]
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            'customer_entity',
            'oc_user',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'comment' => ''
            ]
        );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `di.xml` appears to be incorrect. See the `for` attribute on the `preference` tag. See below I have replaced `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` with `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer`.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer" type="Jason\OCUser\Model\Customer" />
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Model\ActionValidator\RemoveAction">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="protectedModels" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer" xsi:type="string">Jason\OCUser\Model\Customer</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work either. The `loadByEmail()` method is still being called on `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` not my class? @georgeq